# Paypals IPN only sent to the primary email address? Need to send it to different emails

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My developer is trying to get the instant payment notifications from Paypal sent to a secondary Paypal email address.

However Paypal only seems to be sending the IPN to the primary address. He has set up listen page which then does send me a custom IPN to the secondary address, but I also still get the default paypal ipn sent to the primary address anyway.

How can I get the Paypal IPN sent to different email addresses using their API?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IPN messages are sent to an IPN listener, which is a HTTP or HTTPS URL on which a script of yours listens for incoming HTTP POST data.
It has nothing to do with emails of itself (though you can configure an IPN listener to send an email of itself).

Can you please clarify further? Are you sure you don't mean PayPal payment notification emails? These are not 'IPN'.